# How can I update my model in a sailsjs Controller like mongodb updates: a complete document replacement

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, updatemodel

For my purposes, I'd like sailjs's

```
Collection.update(id, {params}, cb)
```

to work like mongodb's update, with the entire model getting swapped out. Is there a way to do this through in a sailsjs Controller?

For example: if I have a model that looks like

```
{ _id: "123...", good: true, bad: false, createdAt: dt, updatedAt: dt }
```

and my {params} are

```
{ _id: "123...", good: false }
```

I'd like the resulting model to be

```
{ _id: "123...", good: false, createdAt: dt, updatedAt: newdt }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "model" and "resulting model"?

Comment: @YannBertrand - I believe by "model" they mean the current instance of an object as it exists in mongo, and the "resulting model" would be what they would like that object instance to contain after the update.

Comment: yep "document" would be a better word.... or "object" to describe the javascript/json object before it becomes a document.